# How to load images fast with python?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, conv-neural-network, python-imaging-library

I'm doing an experiment using Convolutional Neural Network(CNN).

What I want to do is to implement the paper related to CNN.

I have the dataset(this dataset has urls for image and labels for each url/image) for this paper and where I'm stuck is to download image by url and extract pixels for CNN.

My code for this is below:

```
pixels = np.array(data["IMAGE_URL"].apply(image_from_url).tolist())

def image_from_url(_url=None):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(_url) as url:
        f = BytesIO(url.read())

    img = Image.open(f)
    img = img.resize((224, 224), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    arr = array(img,dtype="float32")
```

The sample size is 50000 and with this code, I got an error below:

> ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

I took a few hours to check that error came.
I need some more efficient way to process this.

Numpy and pandas is optimized for handling data but I'm stuck not with data but the preprocessing.

Is there any recommendation to this situation?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you are loading all the images into memory, have you got enough? Also, why don't you do the downloads once, to local disk, then proces from there so you don't have to redownload when you rerun? Can you edit your question to include a link to the paper and dataset?

Comment: @barny Thank you for your advice, then after downloading images into disk, I think the problem still remains with loading images into memory. Should I load images gradually and process them?

Comment: What's the new error?

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you I just solved the error 'Too many files' and now I'm stuck with the issue that the process is killed while runing

Answer (score 0):

If you use Keras, use ImageGenerator.
If you use Pytorch, use torchvision.

In short, when you cannot load everything into memory, you have to load by batch and train by batch using a generator.

Answer (score 0):

Now you've downloaded the images to disk - if you're using keras you can use a keras "generator". This will allow you to use RAM efficiently by only loading the next few images, and it will also massively speed up your code.

This is because keras asynchronously loads the next batches of images, while the GPU trains on the current patch. Try something like this:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32),
                    steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) / 32, max_queue_size=50)
```